# I have 500 tests that execute in jenkins slave. How can I stop the test execution for 1 hour after 100 test case execution

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, automation, cucumber

I have 500 tests as part of my regression suite. I need to wait for 1 hour after 100 tests are executed and then process the remaining tests. How can I achieve this in Selenium Java with cucumber framework?

The reason for waiting is the rest of 400 tests will be executed only when
There is a scheduler that runs for every 30 mins. The rest of the 400 tests are dependent on initial 100 tests. Once initial 100 tests are processed by scheduler, then only I need to validate the rest of the 400 tests. Please suggest me a way to do that in jenkins.

Comment: I thought of having a test with Thread.sleep(long); that waits for one hour. Can someone please give some suggestions on it?

Comment: Can you split the tests into two test runs? Then you could configure a [Jenkins pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) to run the first 100 tests, and the next stage of the pipeline could be scheduled to run at a certain time of day, which would run the remaining 400 tests.